# Need to print triforce using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

I’m trying to program a set of recursive functions that print an ASCII art version of a [Triforce](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triforce), but the spacing isn’t rendering the image correctly.

The code is as follows:

```
def space_f(space):
    if space == 0:
        return
    print(" ", end = "")
    space_f(space - 1)
 
def triangle(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    return '* '*n
    triangle(n - 1)
 
def top_triangle(n, count, base):
    if n == 0:
        return
    space_f(base)
    print(triangle(count - n + 1))
    return top_triangle(n - 1, count, base-1)

def bottom_triangles(n, count, base):
    if n == 0:
        return
    space_f(n-1)
    print(triangle(count - n + 1), triangle(count - n + 1))
    return bottom_triangles(n - 1, count, base-1)


def print_triforce(n):
        if n == 0:
                print(" ")
        height = 2 * n
        base = height - 1
        top_triangle(n, n, base)
        bottom_triangles(n, n, base)
```

Here is the expected output of a call to: `print_triforce(2)`:

```
   * 
  * *
 *   * 
* * * *
```

However, the actual output is:

```
     * 
    * * 
   * * * 
  *  * 
 * *  * * 
* * *  * * *
```

Comment: Besides "can you tell me how to fix my broken code", what exactly is your question about the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not printing enough spaces in your bottom_triangles function and also due to print adding a space when you print multiple variables e.g. `print("a","b")` prints `a b` rather than `ab`

replace it with the following and it should work

```
def bottom_triangles(n, count, base):
    if n == 0:
        return
    space_f(n-1)
    print(triangle(count - n + 1), end="")
    space_f(n-1)
    space_f(n-1)
    print(triangle(count - n + 1))
    return bottom_triangles(n - 1, count, base-1)
```

also the call to `triangle(n - 1)` at the end of the triangle function is never called due to the return statement above it.